# stable homotopy groups and zeta function

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy, riemann-zeta-function, zeta-functions

I have heard during a discussion that there is a well known relation between the stable homotopy groups of a sphere (more precisely the order of stable homotopy groups of localized sphere spectrum with respect to some homology theory $E$) and the values of the zeta function at some integers.

$$ |\pi_{i}^{s}L_{E}\mathbb{S}| =^{?} \zeta(-n)$$
I'm not sure that I understood well, I will be glad if someone can explain this relation.

Comment: Perhaps this is what you mean. Take $E = K(1)$, the first Morava $K$-theory. You can find the homotopy groups $\pi_*L_{K(1)}S^0$, at least when $p$ is odd, in, for example, Lurie's course notes (http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/252xnotes/Lecture35.pdf). The order of the cyclic summand that appears can be expressed as the denominator of a certain expression involving Bernoulli numbers. This is related to the image of $J$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-homomorphism

Comment: @DrewHeard: as this question has been highly upvoted, you should probably promote your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a slightly more fleshed out version of my comment. Let $K(1)$ be the first [Morava $K$-theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Morava+K-theory). When $p$ is odd one can calculate the homotopy groups of the $K(1)$-localised sphere spectrum to be 
$$
\pi_nL_{K(1)}\mathbb{S} = \begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z}_p, &n=0,1\\
\mathbb{Z}/p^{\nu_p(t')+1} & n=2(p-1)t'-1, t' \in \mathbb{Z}.
\end{cases}
$$
Here $\nu_p(x)$ is the $p$-adic valuation of $x$.

Following [Adams](http://math1.unice.fr/~cazanave/Gdt/ImJ/J-II.pdf) define a function $m(l)$ by 
$$
\nu_p(m(l)) = \begin{cases}
0 & l \not \equiv 0 \mod (2(p-1)) \\
1+ \nu_p(l) & l \equiv 0 \mod (2(p-1)).
\end{cases}
$$
Adams shows (following Milnor and Kervaire) that $m(2s)$ is the denominator of $\beta_{2s}/4s$, where $\beta_s$ is the $s$-th Bernoulli number, and the fraction is expressed in the lowest possible form.

Using standard properties of $\nu_p(x)$ there is an equivalence $\nu_p(t')+1  = \nu_p((n+1)/2)+1$. Since $(n+1)/2 \equiv 0 \mod (2(p-1))$ we see
$$
\nu_p(m\left(2\cdot \frac{n+1}{4}\right)) = \nu_p((n+1)/2)+1 
$$
and so the order of $\pi_nL_{K(1)}S^0$ is the denominator of $\beta_{(n+1)/2}/(n+1)$.

**Edit:** Let me try and say something about the image of $J$ then. This is a homomoprhism $J:\pi_nSO \to \pi_n\mathbb{S}$. When $n=4k-1$ the order of the image of $J$ is cyclic of order the denominator of $\beta_{2k}/4k$.  Let $\text{Im}(J_n)_p$ denote the image of the composite  $\pi_nSO \to \pi_n\mathbb{S} \to \pi_n \mathbb{S}_{(p)}$. I believe this is meant to be isomorphic to $\pi_nL_{K(1)}\mathbb{S}$ for $n>1$.

Comment: Would you mind enhancing this nice answer with some elaborations on your comment regarding the image of J?

Comment: @KonradVoelkel - I've added what I believe to be the connection, hopefully it is correct!